# Manipulate element.style in React.js not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am doing a project where I am trying to achieve the hover effects where the element enlarge and background color change. I made it happen toggling class but when I try to make the component I made more reusable by setting the props into the module I realize toggling class maybe not be a good option.So I tried to add inline style when hover.
I find the solution but the way to achieve it doesn't make a lot of sence to me, instead of adding lots of element.style.arribute="somthing"(if there is more than one attribute to change) I would like to just add one object with list of attributes inside.
So instead of

`wrapper.current.style.backgroundColor = "red"; wrapper.current.style.color = "blue"; wrapper.current.style.fontSize = "2rem";`

I believe when there is a lot of attributes to be manipulate it makes more sense if it can be like something like this:

`wrapper.current.style = { backgroundColor: "red",color:blue,fontSize:2rem, };`

But this just won't work for me.

snippet of this component here

```
import React from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
// img:"../sources/computer-and-chair.jpg"
// imgName: "computer and chair"
// subtitle:"First website finnished with vanilla javascript"
function Project(props) {
  const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);
  const wrapper = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isHover) {
      wrapper.current.classList.add("effect");
      // wrapper.current.style.backgroundColor = "red"; work this way but not the way below...
      wrapper.current.style = { backgroundColor: "red" };
    } else {
      wrapper.current.classList.remove("effect");
      // wrapper.current.style.backgroundColor = "transparent"; work this way but not the way below...
      wrapper.current.style = { backgroundColor: "red" };
    }
  }, [isHover]);
  return (
    <section ref={wrapper} className="single-project-container">
      <div className="single-project-image-container">
        <img
          src={props.img}
          alt={props.imgName}
          className="project-image"
          onMouseOver={() => {
            setIsHover(true);
          }}
          onMouseOut={() => {
            setIsHover(false);
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <h1>{props.subtitle}</h1>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Project;
```

I have tried those:

Looked into inline-styling, no direcly answer to my question.
Looked into element.style from MDN, no direcly answer to my question.